# How to display matshow() in Juno for Julia?

Tags: python, julia, juno-ide

I'm trying to display a 2x2 matrix with **matshow()** using PyPlot in Julia for Juno IDE:

```
using PyPlot
pyplot()
a = [rand(5),rand(5)]
display(matshow(a))
```

which displays

```
PyObject <matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x145daa5f8>
```

in the REPL. But, no plots appear. I've also checked the Plots pane and no plots were made.

I am able to use other plotting devices however, such as plot, scatter, and histogram. And they appear as expected in the Plots pane.

Comment: Drop the surrounding `display` and just use `matshow`.

Comment: also drop the `pyplot()` call. Both that call, and the `display` wrapper, are part of the syntax of Plots, which is a different plotting package